# Leaflet map in a flexbox layout

Tags: html, css, leaflet, flexbox

I can't seem to get a (dead simple) `Leaflet.map` to render inside of a `flexbox`. I assume it may be an issue with `invalidateSize`

Dead simple (broken) example: **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ruyenobofi/1/edit?html,css,js,output)**
If you remove the flexbox CSS it'll work: **[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ruyenobofi/2/edit?html,css,js,output)**

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="mapPane"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

**CSS**

```
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

#content {
    flex: 1 1;
    order: 2;
}

#mapPane {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## The power of Flex has you now

There is no height for the map pane to inherit as the parent `#content` is getting the height from its Flex property (telling it to grow). `#mapPane` therefore has the correct  height — **100% of 0 is 0**.

#### Bring the map pane into the Flex world

- Add `display: flex` to `#content`. It will still grow with its existing `flex: 1` property:

  ```
  #content {
      display: flex;
  }
  ```
- Add `flex: 1` to `#mapPane`:

  ```
  #mapPane {
      flex: 1;        
  }
  ```

### Complete Example

```js
$(function() {
  L.map("mapPane");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}
#content {
  flex: 1 1;
  order: 2;
  display: flex;
}
#mapPane {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script><script>L_PREFER_CANVAS = true;</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet-src.js"></script>

  <div id="content">
    <div id="mapPane"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is awesome. I'm trying to use this approach with Django + Foundation 6 + leaflet.js , and I'm getting some funky results. On a map page, where I want a header, content (div around django block content call, calling a template with a leaflet map div), and footer... the leaflet map and the footer don't behave. With the content class on the map div (and no content wrapper div in the base template), the map fills the rest of the page and the footer is gone... Any ideas?

Comment: "The power of Flex has you now" this statement couldn't be any truer. Even after months of using flex, I'm still in awe of it, compared to float behaviour for the past 15 years.

Comment: The problem is again present.
Proof is, the example presented does not work (or no longer).

Comment: @MedMatrix - The map isn't populated, but the actual fix using flex still works just fine. You can tell because the blank map is taking up the entire screen :)